# How can I choose what is blocked when a Modal is opened?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a part of my page not be blocked when a modal opens using bootstrap.

Basically I have a main menu bar at the top of the page (like the black bar here on SO), and sometimes when I open a modal on the page, I would like to leave that menu bar active instead of blocking it out for the modal.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle example. It would probably just take a bit of tweaking the the Z-Index of the modal div and the header div. You would just have to ensure that the header was on top of the modal.

Comment: Something like this (would need to improve it) ? http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/wnv0j55s/

Comment: Yes phillip!  That was so simple, I was thinking it would be a pain for some reason :)

Comment: If one of you wants to put it in as an answer I'll accept

Comment: @trevis slapping position relative + z-index in the JS may cause some dissonance. Best to keep CSS within the CSS file and JS in the JS file. Just always have the Z-index be higher than the modal, even if the modal isn't showing.

Comment: @Tevis , I would post the answer, but as I wrote - it should to be improved (it's more like a suggestion where you would start with). In some cases you may have problems after updating elements CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ensure that the Z-index of your menu was greater than your modal. You can do this in plain CSS.

[Bootstraps default modal Z-index is 1040, so increasing the headers z-index to 1041 would suffice.](http://jsfiddle.net/wnv0j55s/7/)

```
.menu { 
 z-index: 1041;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Ran into another issue.  If I put an input text into the menu, the input cannot be refocused after the modal comes out: http://jsfiddle.net/wnv0j55s/8/

Comment: Modals by definition are supposed to disable all elements that aren't within the modal, so bootstrap was constructed in such a way to accomplish this. Modals are supposed to force a user to enter data and prevent them from navigating away from the modal unless they complete necessary instructions. Instead of rewriting the bootstrap framework, maybe popovers might be a better option if you want your users to interact with other items on your site. - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers